# CSS / HTML Header streches out of the screen on the right side. How to avoid that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a small Website but i have a problem with the header. Despite I set in the header the CSS

`width:100%  position: fixed`

it is alsways streching out of the screen.
I tried to  add this but it didn't work

```
html, body {
 margin: 0;
}
```

Here is the code of the Page. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

```css
/*-------------------
Base Style
---------------------*/

body{font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;}

a{text-decoration: none;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p{color: #000; padding-bottom: 30px;}


.big-text{font-size: 70px; font-weight: 900;}
.medium-text{font-size: 40px;}
.normal-text{font-size: 20px;}
.small-text{font-size: 14px;}


.intro-text{text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;}

.button{padding:18px 28px; background: #316bff;color:#fff;display: inline-block; border-radius: 4px;} /*sopra e sotto 18, destra sinistra 28*/

/*-------------------
Header
---------------------*/


.header{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    background: #000;
}

.logo{
    border: 1px solid red;

}

.menu{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;

}
.menu li{  display: inline-block;}
.menu li a{  color: #fff;padding:15px;display: block;}

.cta{
    border: 1px solid red;

}

/*-------------------
Hero
---------------------*/
.hero{
    background: yellow;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex; width: 100%;align-items: center;

}

.hero__content{
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


  /*Reset del padding degli elementi applicando il padding degli elementi all'interno degli elementi e non all'esterno
  Evitiamo sostanzialmente problemi di sovrapposizioni di elementi*/
  
  *,
  *:before,
  *after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" integrity="sha512-NmLkDIU1C/C88wi324HBc+S2kLhi08PN5GDeUVVVC/BVt/9Izdsc9SVeVfA1UZbY3sHUlDSyRXhCzHfr6hmPPw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    
    
</head>
<body>

<div class="header"> 
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logoFake.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li ><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Single</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Contact</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <div class="cta">
        <a href="" class="button">Contact</a>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="hero">
    <div class="hero__content">
        <p class="intro-text">Intro Text</p>
        <h1 class="big-text">Title of the page</h1>
        <a href="" class="button">Discover More</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: probably it causes by the padding , i'll suggest to read more about box-sizing property

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean the padding of the Button?

Comment: If you set `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.header` all works fine

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It worksssssssssssss...I have been trying the whole afternooon!!!!!!!!!!thank you!